# Balanced quantiling over two dimensions

Tags: r, quantiles

Having data in two columns:

```
> set.seed(1)
> N = 1000
> XY = as.data.frame(matrix(cbind(round(runif(N),2),
+                                 round(runif(N),2)),N,2))
> colnames(XY) <- c('X','Y')
```

I have divided the data into deciles in two dimensions:

```
> colX_deciles = quantile(XY[,'X'], probs=seq(0,1,1/10))
> colY_deciles = quantile(XY[,'Y'], probs=seq(0,1,1/10))
> XY['X_decile'] <- findInterval(XY[,'X'],colX_deciles,all.inside = TRUE)
> XY['Y_decile'] <- findInterval(XY[,'Y'],colY_deciles,all.inside = TRUE)
> colX_deciles
   0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
0.000 0.109 0.200 0.310 0.400 0.480 0.600 0.710 0.800 0.910 1.000 
> colY_deciles
   0%   10%   20%   30%   40%   50%   60%   70%   80%   90%  100% 
0.000 0.089 0.170 0.280 0.380 0.480 0.590 0.700 0.810 0.900 1.000 
> xt = table(XY[,c('X_decile','Y_decile')])
> rownames(xt) <- round(colX_deciles[1:10],2)
> colnames(xt) <- round(colY_deciles[1:10],2)
> xt
        Y_decile
X_decile  0 0.09 0.17 0.28 0.38 0.48 0.59 0.7 0.81 0.9
    0     5   14    9   10    8   10    9  16   11   8
    0.11  7   11   11   12    9   10    7  13   12   6
    0.2  10    7    8   10   15    8   13   7   10   9
    0.31  7   11   11    8   14   11    9  16    6  10
    0.4  14    5   11    9    7    6    9   9    7  11
    0.48 12    8    8    6   16   11   15   6   14  17
    0.6   9   12   15    6   10   13    7   7   10  11
    0.71 12    7    7    8    6   11   13  11   13  12
    0.8  10    8   10   10   12   15    6   7   10   7
    0.91 14    9   15   12    8   11    7   9    8  13
```

**Question:** Is there some more balanced way to do the determination of deciles *for the both dimensions at the same time* than creating the deciles separately in both dimensions and then combining the result?

For uniform distribution that might not be a problem, but for a more general distribution there might be a more balanced quantile cut points that would take into account the distribution of the cases better in two dimensions.

Comment: Quantiles are based on the idea of order, and order is a concept most useful for 1-dimensional quantities. For example, $ℝ$ is an ordered field whereas $ℂ$ isn't. So I don't think there's a natural generalization of quantiles to $n$ dimensions, but I could be wrong. The median, at least, has a generalization to the geometric median and the medoid.

Comment: Actually there seem to be natural generalization, but it additionally requires also distance function with respect to the third dimension $z$. In the above table it could be the distance $|z_{i,j} - \langle z_{i,j} \rangle|$ from the mean count $\langle z_{i,j} \rangle$ of the number of elements. The full problem can then be interpreted as is then the minimization problem: $\min \sum (z_{i,j} - \langle z_{i,j} \rangle)^2$.